# How can I do a structure type conversion like this?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, type-conversion

say if I have two structure types:

```
typedef struct
{
   unsigned int * a;
   char * b;
   char * c;
}TYPEA;

typedef struct
{
   unsigned int * a;
   unsigned int * b;
}TYPEB;
```

And I also have a pointer array, which contains pointer pointing to `TYPEA` types:

```
TYPEA* AArray[1] =
{
   &ga,
};
```

`ga` is defined as:

```
TYPEA ga =
{
   &num1,
   &b,
   &c,
};
```

If I have another `TYPEA` var defined, I can modify `AArray[0]`'s content's value, like this:

```
TYPEA another_ga =
{
   &num3,
   &b,
   &c,
};

void change_AArray()
{
   *AArray[0] = another_ga;
}
```

This works perfectly good, but the question is, as `TYPEA` and `TYPEB`'s first 32bits are same(Both are `unsigned int`) is it possible for me to change `AArray`'s `ga`'s content to a `TYPEB` structure?

Here are my attempts:

```
void change_AArray()
{
   /* *AArray[0] = another_ga; */

   /* Compile Error */
   /* *AArray[0] = gb; */

   /* Compile Error */
   /* *AArray[0] = (TYPEA)gb; */

   /* Passed compile, but AArray[0] is not changed */
   /* AArray[0] = (TYPEA*)&gb; */
}
```

I then tried to add another pointer and put it in `AArray[0]` instead of using `&ga`, but it can't pass compile stage, I think C is requiring a constant in the initialize list.

```
TYPEA * pga = &ga;
TYPEA* AArray[1] =
{
   pga, // error, needs a constant expression.
};
void change_AArray()
{
   AArray[0] = (TYPEA*)&gb;
}
```

Is it possible to do the type conversion?

The entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
   unsigned int * a;
   char * b;
   char * c;
}TYPEA;

typedef struct
{
   unsigned int * a;
   unsigned int * b;
}TYPEB;

int num1 = 10, num2 = 20, num3 = 30;
char b = 'b', c = 'c';

TYPEA ga =
{
   &num1,
   &b,
   &c,
};

TYPEA another_ga =
{
   &num3,
   &b,
   &c,
};

TYPEB gb =
{
   &num2,
   &num3,
};

TYPEA* AArray[1] =
{
   &ga,
};

void change_AArray()
{
   *AArray[0] = another_ga;
   /* How can I do this conversion? */
   /* *AArray[0] = gb; */
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   printf("ga.a: %d\n", *ga.a);
   printf("gb.b: %d\n", *gb.a);

   change_AArray();

   printf("After calling change_AArray()\n");
   printf("ga.a: %d\n", *ga.a);
   printf("gb.b: %d\n", *gb.a);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void change_AArray()
{   
   *AArray[0] = *((TYPEA*) &gb);  //#1
   /* error:
   *(AArray[0]) = (TYPEA) gb;     //#2
   */
}
```

You can use #1 for your purpose.

If use #2, gcc reports an error:
error: conversion to non-scalar type requested

Questions are:
- What's scalar/non-scalar type?
- What does this error message mean?
- Why #2 fails?

What's scalar/non-scalar type?
int, char, pointers are scalar type, and a structure is not.
See details here,http://herbert.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/en/prgmsc1/docs/part2a.pdf

What does this error message mean?
If you do assignment between scalar and non-scalar type, you'll get this error.

Why #2 fails?
For `*(AArray[0]) = (TYPEA) gb;`, both sides are non-scalar types. So, it looks like it shouldn't get the above error.
However, C doesn't allow cast between structures. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9f2bsy2.aspx.

A test program,

```
struct a{ int i;};
struct b{ int i; };

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct a aaa;
    struct b bbb;
    bbb = (struct b)aaa;

    return 0;
}
```

gcc reports an error:
`error: conversion to non-scalar type requested`

So to conclude, the reason for failure of #2 is that C language doesn't allow cast between structures.

Comment: C++ does allow cast between structures, but you must define a function that specifies how the cast is done. There is no default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use union

```
union UNION_AB {
  TYPEA a;
  TYPEB b;
};

UNION_AB* UARRAY[1] = { &ua };
```

Comment: This will work if you only ever access the first field (`UARRAY[0]->a.a` or equivalently `UARRAY[0]->b.a`), since unions of structs do have defined behavior if those structs have compatible members, but once you go past those, you enter Undefined Behavior land.

Comment: Not only then; if the code always accesses the structure that is in the union at that time, it is defined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast two different types of `struct` directly, you have to assign the fields like this:

```
(*AArray[0]).a = gb.a;
```

Comment: I think I can if `AArray[0]` is a `lvalue`, but seems like initialize lists can't have `lvalues` inside.

Comment: @shengy Basically what you are trying to do is `struct foo a = struct bar b`. Well, you can't do that directly or through a pointer.